# Rails App- Sync "staging" db with "production"

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, synchronization

I have a rails CMS app that manages content for a production web server (not a rails app).  They are on two boxes.

[image: separate]

The database in staging needs to copy data (database is very small,<1MB) to the production database. This needs to be done manually, not thru replication.  To make it more difficult the production server is only accessible thru SSH, access for other services is not allowed (typical secure environment).

I've tried writing some rake/Capistrano tasks to do a mysql dump on the staging server and import it into the production server, although this would lock the production database, making requests fail.  The production server cannot be brought down during the syncs.

What are my options?

Comment: Could you just disable table locking ( only for doing the dump  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the gem [table_syncer](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=27509) to be everything I needed, hope this helps someone else.